# How to create a non-deterministic function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, function, guid

I am trying to set up a GUID generator for my MySQL database. I am attempting to use a user-defined function within MySQL to generate the GUID:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNextGlobalIdSequence
    () RETURNS BIGINT(8) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE _global_id_sequence set _global_id=last_insert_id(_global_id+1);
    RETURN last_insert_id();
END
```

As this is a non-deterministic function, MySQL is puking with the following error:

> "This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in
>   its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use
>   the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)"

I read that this is thrown because MySQL cannot guarantee the replicability of the data. I thought that this could be avoided by changing my binlog_format from STATEMENT to MIXED (or ROW), which would make sense because I would have assumed that MySQL would log the non-deterministic executions as ROW and therefore be able to replicate effectively. However, I am still getting the above error.

My question is, how can this function be created and used (if at all)? If it can't, what alternative methods are available for having a custom-rolled GUID generator working for MySQL?

P.s. I am aware of Snowflake, but really want to know if it is possible to do directly within MySQL.

Answer (score -1):

The usual way for surrogate keys in MySQL is using [auto increment column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).

For global IDs on database level, then you need one single table just for all your IDs.

Comment: This does not generate GUID's across a database.

Comment: @JoePrivett You want an ID that is unique on database and not on table level? That is indeed very much possible with auto increment column. You can have one single table for all your IDs.

Comment: The GUID needs to be hand-rolled so that it is sequential and unique across my cluster of databases. Even if you had one table in a database to generate the ID's how would you increment and retrieve this ID from this table (I am using PHP for example)?

Comment: Well in java you have a method PreparedStatement.getGeneratedKey after you execute an update.
As for PHP and MySQL, look at the documentation, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-functionality-last-insert-id.html and http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: Isn't it a really bad idea to generate a GUID at application level? The time between retrieving the GUID from the central table and the adding if the GUID to the SQL statement (application level) might cause the GUID sequence in the destination table to be out of sync.